# Find a better way to convert map to json using jackson when some values are already known as json strings

Tags: java, json, jackson

I know it is very easy to use Jackson to convert Map to Json. But I want to know if there is a better way for my situation. Below is my code.

```
String jsonInfo = "{\"attr\":\"value\",\"attr2\",\"value2\"}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
map.put("name","daniel");
map.put("info",mapper.readValue(jsonInfo, new TypeReference<Map>(){}));

String finalJsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
```

As you can see, even I already know jsonInfo is a json string. For this part, I convert it into a map then finally let Jackson convert it to json again. Is there any better way that I can avoid such duplicated work?

Comment: why are you using Jackson in the first place when you know the string is JSON. And then converting it into an object and converting in String?

Comment: Don't serialize it to a `Map`. Just get the `JSONObject` from Jackson and modify it

Comment: @Nishant - he has some JSON in a `String` and wants to add `"name":"daniel"` to it. Doing it by hand is rather tedius.

Comment: @Nishant as you can see my code, jsonInfo is part of my final json.

Comment: @Brian Roach I am not very sure what you mean. Any more hints I can follow? Thanks.

Comment: @Willy Sorry - got my object names messed up between parsers :) See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want to use Jackson to parse your JSON into its tree structure where you can then add data. This eliminates the extra step of serializing/deserializing to a POJO (or Map)

```
String jsonInfo = "{\"attr\":\"value\",\"attr2\":\"value2\"}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode origNode = mapper.readTree(jsonInfo);

ObjectNode rootNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
rootNode.put("name", "daniel");
rootNode.put("info", origNode);

String finalJson = rootNode.toString();
```

Your `finalJson` then becomes:

> {"name":"daniel","info":{"attr":"value","attr2":"value2"}}

Note that `JsonNode` is immutable, but can be cast to an `ObjectNode` if you wanted to modify your original JSON as well.